Getting error to resolve the dns "auth2.googleapis.com" on mobile app but its working while run app on laptop
I am trying to integrate the firebase storage in mobile app. I can upload & download file from firebase correctly by app if i run it on my laptop. When I run the app on mobile, Seeing below error -
07-01 15:18:59.702 20954 20982 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Making request] POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
07-01 15:18:59.705 20954 20982 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Starting new HTTPS connection (1)] oauth2.googleapis.com:443
07-01 15:18:59.705 20954 20982 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Incremented Retry for (url='/token')] Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
07-01 15:18:59.706 20954 20982 I python  : [WARNING] [Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7580f5f3d0>: Failed to resolve 'oauth2.googleapis.com' ([Errno 7] No address associated with hostname)")'] /token
07-01 15:18:59.706 20954 20982 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Starting new HTTPS connection (2)] oauth2.googleapis.com:443
07-01 15:18:59.706 20954 20982 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Incremented Retry for (url='/token')] Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
07-01 15:18:59.706 20954 20982 I python  : [WARNING] [Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x75835a9b10>: Failed to resolve 'oauth2.googleapis.com' ([Errno 7] No address associated with hostname)")'] /token
07-01 15:18:59.707 20954 20982 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Starting new HTTPS connection (3)] oauth2.googleapis.com:443
07-01 15:18:59.707 20954 20982 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Incremented Retry for (url='/token')] Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
07-01 15:18:59.707 20954 20982 I python  : [WARNING] [Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x74ffeead50>: Failed to resolve 'oauth2.googleapis.com' ([Errno 7] No address associated with hostname)")'] /token
07-01 15:18:59.708 20954 20982 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Starting new HTTPS connection (4)] oauth2.googleapis.com:443
07-01 15:18:59.708 20954 20982 I python  : Error reading file: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7583afdbd0>: Failed to resolve 'oauth2.googleapis.com' ([Errno 7] No address associated with hostname)"))
07-01 15:18:59.708 20954 20982 I python  : None
And its not able to resolve the DNS of oaut2. Can anyone help me on it ?
Can any one help me to find the root cause of this
